# Can you hide web service ASMX calls from pack sniffers?

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, call, packet

I am new to web services so I created a web service to replace my current in-app DB transactions. I wanted things to be safer so that is why I went this way.

When using a free packet sniffer, it instantly grabs my web service ASMX call. The problem with this is that using a program such as fiddler they can easily see the data going back and forth and even worse set up a auto responder.

Is there a way to hide the calls being sent to the web service to hide from packet sniffers? Or at least make it more difficult to see the calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expose it over a secured channel (such as SSL) only for transport level security.

Alternatively, you may choose to implement [WS-Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) to validate the identity of the callers, sign the payload or encrypt the payload (partially or fully); or any combination of  the above.

Here is an article that talks about this in the context of ASP.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188947.aspx